# Do we always need to show well-definedness when showing that a structure is a binary structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that we have a set $G = \{x \in \mathbb{Q} | x > 1 \}$ and we will show that $<G, •>$ is a binary structure, where for any $a,b \in G$, $a•b= 2ab - a - b$.

What I know about well-definedness of the operation is that if $a=a'$ and $b=b'$, then $a•b=a'•b'$.

I found that similar problems present a solutions for both well-definedness of the operation and the closure of the set under that operation. But some problems only present a solution about closure. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be certain because I'm not sure what "some problems" you are thinking of, but I would say these two things:

Yes, when defining a binary operation on a set it is necessary to prove it is well-defined, because that is part of the definition of "binary operation," that it is a function $G\times G\to G$.  Technically the "closure" part of this is in there too because you can't say "$\to G$" without having established closure.

*Closure* is most useful when proving a subset $H$ of a binary structure $(G,\star)$ is another binary structure. In that case, you already know $\star$ is well-defined, and you just need to know that $\ast$ restricted to $H\times H$ actually produces items in $H$.  Maybe this is a type of problem you were looking at, too.

---

If it seems like a solution is really not checking well-definedness, then perhaps the author thought there is a reason that it is obvious for that case, or perhaps they simply forgot.